# ActionBar tamanho texto dinâmico

Tags: java, android, actionbar

Como colocar o texto na actionbar com tamanho dinâmico? 
Necessito de dar set em tamanhos distintos de texto e que tenham que enquadrar de forma dinâmica.

```
public void setarTituloActionBar(String nome){
        setTitle(nome);

    }
```

O set está 100%.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como assim tamanho dinâmico?

Comment: O texto consegue saber qual o tamanho limite da ActionBar e redimensionar o texto, no exemplo acima tenho um nome muito grande para a ActionBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Recomendo você a separar os dois textos em titulo e subtitulo**

```
 public void setTitles(String titulo, String subtitulo){
    toolbar.setTitle(titulo);
    toolbar.setSubtitle(subtitulo);

}

setTitles("Tocando","Nome Grande de música");
```

Comment: Obg man! Até mais